# Why can't I enable virtualization

Tags: bios, virtualization

I'm trying to enable virtualization on my [laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/EE/content/model/NH.Q2SEL.010) but I cannot find the option to do so in BIOS. This is where it should be (I think) but it isn't:

[image]

I'm quite I should be able to enable virtualization or at least according to this:

[image]

Anyway, hopefully, someone knows what's wrong.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Please edit your question to include this vital information.  However, your question is not clear, since your screenshot already indicate VT-x and VT-d are enabled.  What are you attempting to do exactly, please edit your question, to include this vital information

Comment: Those _are_ the options - VTX & VTD are 2 parts of Intel's Virtualisation tech. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I/O_MMU_virtualization_(AMD-Vi_and_Intel_VT-d)

Comment: To the OP - why do you think it's _not_ enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those *are* the virtualization options.

VTX and VTD are 2 parts of Intel's virtualization tech - CPU and chipset components respectively.

> Previously codenamed "Vanderpool", VT-x represents Intel's technology for virtualization on the x86 platform. On November 13, 2005, Intel released two models of Pentium 4 (Model 662 and 672) as the first Intel processors to support VT-x. The CPU flag for VT-x capability is "vmx"; in Linux, this can be checked via /proc/cpuinfo, or in macOS via sysctl machdep.cpu.features.

[Central processing unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Central_processing_unit)

> Intel's "Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O" (VT-d),[43] included in most high-end (but not all) Nehalem and newer Intel processors

[Chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Chipset)